# Expanding a table and filling in the blanks r

Tags: r, loops

I have a table and an example is given below.

```
tab <- matrix(c(seq(0, 130, by = 10), sample(100, size = 14)), ncol=2)
tab[1, 1] <- 1
colnames(tab) <- c("A", "B")
```

I need to expand the table so i have a full sequence of values from 1:140 in A and the values of B fill out to match A.

So i would then have 1:9 in A and whatever value in the original table ([1, 2]) filling out those spaces. Then from 10:19 in A and whatever value in [2, 2] filling out B.

I hope I have explained myself. I can only think of doing it manually in a loop but not too sure how to code this.

Any help much appriciated.

Comment: When you say whatever value in original table [1,2], it is 83 (as you didn't specify a set.seed).  So, is it c(1:9, 83)`

Comment: By "filling out", do you mean interpolation or filling-down? What are B's values between A's 1:10?

Comment: I see I wasnt clear enough. My fault. Still getting used to this. Thought my repex was good! I was trying to save time than writing out the table in full. However @r2evans managed to solve it for me even with my poor explination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *interpolate* `B` on `A`'s expansion, then we can use `approx` for that:

```r
approximated <- approx(tab[,1], tab[,2], xout = seq(min(tab[,1]), max(tab[,1])))
approximated
# $x
#   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
#  [30]  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58
#  [59]  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87
#  [88]  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116
# [117] 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130
# $y
#   [1]  49.0  50.8  52.6  54.3  56.1  57.9  59.7  61.4  63.2  65.0  61.0  57.0  53.0  49.0  45.0  41.0  37.0  33.0  29.0
#  [20]  25.0  29.9  34.8  39.7  44.6  49.5  54.4  59.3  64.2  69.1  74.0  68.4  62.8  57.2  51.6  46.0  40.4  34.8  29.2
#  [39]  23.6  18.0  26.2  34.4  42.6  50.8  59.0  67.2  75.4  83.6  91.8 100.0  94.7  89.4  84.1  78.8  73.5  68.2  62.9
#  [58]  57.6  52.3  47.0  44.7  42.4  40.1  37.8  35.5  33.2  30.9  28.6  26.3  24.0  28.7  33.4  38.1  42.8  47.5  52.2
#  [77]  56.9  61.6  66.3  71.0  72.8  74.6  76.4  78.2  80.0  81.8  83.6  85.4  87.2  89.0  83.8  78.6  73.4  68.2  63.0
#  [96]  57.8  52.6  47.4  42.2  37.0  35.3  33.6  31.9  30.2  28.5  26.8  25.1  23.4  21.7  20.0  20.6  21.2  21.8  22.4
# [115]  23.0  23.6  24.2  24.8  25.4  26.0  23.7  21.4  19.1  16.8  14.5  12.2   9.9   7.6   5.3   3.0
```

This can be turned into a matrix fairly easily,

```r
out <- cbind(A = approximated$x, B = approximated$y)
head(out,3); tail(out,3)
#      A    B
# [1,] 1 49.0
# [2,] 2 50.8
# [3,] 3 52.6
#          A   B
# [128,] 128 7.6
# [129,] 129 5.3
# [130,] 130 3.0
```

If instead you mean a step-function in a way, then add the `method="constant"` instead:

```r
approximated <- approx(tab[,1], tab[,2], xout = seq(min(tab[,1]), max(tab[,1])), 
                       method="constant")
out <- cbind(A = approximated$x, B = approximated$y)
head(out,11); tail(out,11)
#        A  B
#  [1,]  1 49
#  [2,]  2 49
#  [3,]  3 49
#  [4,]  4 49
#  [5,]  5 49
#  [6,]  6 49
#  [7,]  7 49
#  [8,]  8 49
#  [9,]  9 49
# [10,] 10 65
# [11,] 11 65
#          A  B
# [120,] 120 26
# [121,] 121 26
# [122,] 122 26
# [123,] 123 26
# [124,] 124 26
# [125,] 125 26
# [126,] 126 26
# [127,] 127 26
# [128,] 128 26
# [129,] 129 26
# [130,] 130  3
```

FYI, I use `seq(min(tab[,1]), max(tab[,1]))` in order to do this programmatically, not assuming that `A` ranges from 1 to its max. This can be simplified a little if that's the intent and design.

Comment: And yes I did mean in a step function. I dont have enough rep to upvote but have givien it a solution tick.

Comment: You should have enough vote, I think the limit's 15, isn't it? (Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: now i can :) Thanks for the help!